# Ng-repeat isn't reading from the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I work with angular & ng-repeat at work, which is why I am so perplexed as to why this won't render. It's probably something silly I'm overlooking, but I've spent enough time on it that it merits asking someone else for a hint.

The relevant bits:

JS

```
  .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, dataAPI){
    dataAPI.getIndex().then(function(res) {
      console.log('server response', res);
      $scope.notes = res;
    });
```

Jade

```
  h1 Hello this is the list
  div(ng-controller='ListCtrl')
    div(ng-repeat='note in notes')
      div {{ note.dist_path }}
```

The console log of data loaded (array of objects)

```
server response [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

No errors in the console. I inspect the scope, and I see exactly what I would expect. An object of arrays.

Comment: But a debugging breakpoint on $scope.notes = res and see if "res" has something else attached to it. That's probably where your real data is sitting at.

Comment: This might be obvious but does each object in `res` have a `dist_path` property?

Comment: @Phil Yeah, does have it.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I tried that early on. All is I see is the pure collection I was expecting

Comment: Inspect the HTML document as well. I've mocked it up as a demo here, albeit without Jade and it works fine ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/Vl5AFJ2TzXYhgPxiokm9?p=preview

Comment: What is `dataAPI`? Is it an angular `$resource` or does it use `$http`? If it uses some kind of non-angular asynchronous call, you may need to run `$scope.$apply()` after assigning `$scope.notes`

Comment: @Phil It uses angular's $http.

Comment: In the DOM, I see angular's ng-repeat comment just inside the controller declaration. but no div inside.

Comment: @Phil Your hunch re: $http was right! In the dataAPI I'm using q to return a promise, not $http directly. I called $scope.apply() in the controller and it came to life. Thank you!

Comment: Just above `div(ng-repeat='note in notes')` can you add `div {{ notes }}`

Comment: That doesn't make sense - do you mean an external library Q, instead of $q?

Comment: @BryceJohnson that's odd. `$q` should work (or did you literally mean `q` as in the *other* promise library)

Comment: the other promise library 'q' -- I'm used to using it elsewhere, and forgot about $q. Guess I should stick to what's provided to avoid these sorts of hiccups

Comment: @BryceJohnson just use the promise from `$http`, no need to introduce further indirection

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my `dataAPI` method `getIndex` was using an external library (q) to resolve the request, rather than leaving it up to angular's `$http` and `$q`. So I needed to call `$scope.$apply()` after setting the scope variable to alert angular of the change. Or just use angular's built in `$q` or work with the promise returned by `$http`.